# ffmpeg: set the language of an audio stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have 3 files: video.mp4, audionl.mp4 & audioeng.mp4.
I tried adding them all together in 1 output.mp4 file like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i audionl.mp4 -i audioeng.mp4  -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -metadata:s:a:0 language=nl -metadata:s:a:0 title="NL" -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng  -metadata:s:a:1 title="ENG" -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy  -movflags faststart output.mp4 2>&1
```

This is the output I see from ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.9 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libpulse --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr1 --disable-mipsdspr2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libzvbi --enable-avresample --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --enable-libutvideo --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-vaapi --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42dash
    creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
  Duration: 00:20:52.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1172 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1168 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audionl.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomM4A mp42dash
    creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
  Duration: 00:20:52.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 96 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'audioeng.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomM4A mp42dash
    creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
  Duration: 00:20:52.78, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42dash
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1168 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(nl): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      title           : NL
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-04 06:35:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      title           : ENG
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0xbb1320] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=31320 fps=20993 q=-1.0 Lsize=  204217kB time=00:20:52.79 bitrate=1335.4kbits/s
video:178734kB audio:23867kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.797284%
```

As you can see in there: "Stream #0:0(eng)", "Stream #0:1(nl)" & "Stream #0:2(eng)".
So that looks fine.

But when I open it in VLC, I see under Audio tracks:
NL - [English]
ENG - [English]

So I went back to check on ffmpeg with "ffmpeg -i output.mp4":

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:20:52.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1335 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1168 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

And here they are English again...

Afterwards I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audionl.mp4 -c:a copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=nl output.mp4
```

But also that failed to set the correct language on the output file...
I'm at a loss here and hope someone can help me set these languages correctly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

FFmpeg expects [ISO 639-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) codes for languages, so for Dutch, it's either

```
-metadata:s:a:0 language=dut
```

or

```
-metadata:s:a:0 language=nld
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was not immediately clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use commands like so

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a:m:language:eng output.mp4
```

please use -map 0:v because it selects the video track along with the audio one or else you will just transcode the audio to your output.